# nginx reverse proxy to wordpress docker container hangs with HTTP 301 error

Tags: wordpress, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I’m trying to use nginx as a reverse proxy for multiple docker containers running wordpress.  The nginx instance and docker are running on Ubuntu 16.04.3 server.  I have been testing this out on my local dev environment with Vagrant using a separate Ubuntu box for nginx and another for docker.  The vagrant configuration works as expected, but when I try to make a similar configuration on a single physical Ubuntu server the route to the wordpress docker container hangs and eventually returns an HTTP 301 error.

Note: Using a similar nginx reverse proxy configuration for other docker containers listening on different port works.  For example, running Jenkins in docker and using a reverse proxy to that container works successfully.

Here are the configurations I am using with Vagrant and then on my physical Ubuntu server:

Working solution with Vagrant and Two separate Ubuntu boxes

**Vagrant Configuration**

Nginx running in a separate Ubuntu Box

Setting local host file
/etc/hosts  10.10.45.10 - wp.dev

**nginx configuration**

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name wp.dev;
error_log /var/log/nginx/wp_dev_error.log debug;

    location / {
        proxy_pass      http://10.10.45.11:8080;
        proxy_redirect  off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

***Wordpress docker configuration***

**Docker-compose.yml file:**

```
  version: "2"
  services:
  my-wpdb:
    image: mariadb
    ports:
      - "8081:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: <some_password>
  my-wp:
    image: wordpress
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    links:
      - my-wpdb:mysql
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: <some_password>
```

**Run docker container**

docker-compose up -d

**Route**

wp.dev (10.10.45.10) →  docker_wp (10.10.45.11 port 8080)

Curl test:  curl wp.dev  --  SUCCESS
10.10.45.1 - - [18/Aug/2017:21:38:37 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 51638 "-" "curl/7.54.0"

**Broken Configuration**

/etc/nginx/sites-available/sub1.mydomain.com.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name sub1.mydomain.com;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain_nonssl_error.log debug;

    location / {

        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    }
}
```

Docker-compose file for wordpress docker container is the same as the vagrant configuration above.

**Testing configuration and results**

Curl test:  curl  ..com

```
159.203.127.57 - - [18/Aug/2017:15:37:52 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "curl/7.47.0"
```

The page hangs and I see in the header a HTTP 301 error.

curl -v http://

```
* Rebuilt URL to: http://<my_testdomain>/
*   Trying xx.xx.xx.91...
* Connected to sub1.mydomain.com (xx.xx.xx.91) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: sub1.mydomain.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Sat, 19 Aug 2017 15:05:38 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.31
**< Location: http://<my_test_domain>:8080/**
< 
* Connection #0 to host <my_test_domain> left intact
```

Note: that the route continues to use the destination port in the URL.  I don’t see this in my Vagrant configuration.  This may be the problem.

I’ve tried different nginx configuration to hide the destination port but nothing seems to work.

Here are some specific questions that may help troubleshoot this problem:

1. How can I enable more debug information with nginx.  I’m using the following “error_log” setting but would like to enable “verbose” logging to determine how routing is working.

error_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain_nonssl_error.log debug;

2. Why is the destination port still showing in the URL when I run nginx reverse proxy on the same machine, but a similar configuration in Vagrant running separate boxes hides the port and uses the original URL in the request?
3. Could the problem be in the Docker wordpress/Apache container that is causing the 301 HTTP error?

I’ve been working on this problem for several days and have not been able to resolve the issue.  Thanks in advance for your help.

**Nginx Log file of reverse proxy **

```
    2017/08/28 09:53:14 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http script copy: "X-Real-IP: "
2017/08/28 09:53:14 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http script var: "168.179.61.161"
2017/08/28 09:53:14 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http script copy: "
"
2017/08/28 09:53:14 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http script copy: "X-Forwarded-For: "
2017/08/28 09:53:14 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http script var: "168.179.61.161"
2017/08/28 09:53:14 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http script copy: "
"
2017/08/28 09:53:14 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http script copy: "Connection: close
"
2017/08/28 09:53:14 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http script copy: ""
2017/08/28 09:53:14 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http script copy: ""
2017/08/28 09:53:14 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http script copy: ""
2017/08/28 09:53:14 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http script copy: ""
2017/08/28 09:53:14 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http proxy header: "user-agent: curl/7.53.0"
2017/08/28 09:53:14 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http proxy header: "accept: */*"
2017/08/28 09:53:14 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http proxy header:
"GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: <mydevsite>
X-Real-IP: 168.179.61.161
X-Forwarded-For: 168.179.61.161
Connection: close
user-agent: curl/7.53.0
accept: */*

… snip ….

2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http upstream request: "/?"
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http upstream process header
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 malloc: 000055D755D248F0:4096
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 recv: fd:29 246 of 4096
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http proxy status 301 "301 Moved Permanently"
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 posix_memalign: 000055D755D168A0:4096 @16
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http proxy header: "Date: Mon, 28 Aug 2017 15:53:14 GMT"
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http proxy header: "Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)"
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http proxy header: "X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.31"
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http proxy header: "Location: http://<mydevsite>:8080/"
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http proxy header: "Content-Length: 0"
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http proxy header: "Connection: close"
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http proxy header: "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http proxy header done
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 xslt filter header
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http2 header filter
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http2 output header: ":status: 301"
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http2 output header: "server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)"
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http2 output header: "date: Mon, 28 Aug 2017 15:53:15 GMT"
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http2 output header: "content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http2 output header: "content-length: 0"
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http2 output header: "location: http://<mydevsite>:8080/"
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http2 output header: "x-powered-by: PHP/5.6.31"
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http2 output header: "strict-transport-security: max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains"
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http2 output header: "x-frame-options: DENY"
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http2 output header: "x-content-type-options: nosniff"
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http2:1 create HEADERS frame 000055D755D16B78: len:200
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http cleanup add: 000055D755D16C60
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http2 frame out: 000055D755D16B78 sid:1 bl:1 len:200
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 SSL buf copy: 9
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 SSL buf copy: 200
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http2:1 HEADERS frame 000055D755D16B78 was sent
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http2 frame sent: 000055D755D16B78 sid:1 bl:1 len:200
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http cacheable: 0
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http proxy filter init s:301 h:0 c:0 l:0
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 http upstream process upstream
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 pipe read upstream: 1
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 pipe preread: 0
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 readv: 1, last:3850
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 pipe recv chain: 0
2017/08/28 09:53:15 [debug] 11853#11853: *1 pipe buf free s:0 t:1 f:0 000055D755D248F0, pos 000055D755D249E6, size: 0 file: 0, size: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Before seeing you trying to debug in nginx side, i would suggest you to try how the upstreams are active for nginx. Could post the output for http://localhost:8080 from nginx ?

--
Mohammed Azfar

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I have added a shortened version of the nginx log file at the bottom of the question.  The log show an SSL handshake that seems to work.  Then it does an upstream to localhost:8080 but returns with a HTTP 301 error.  The final URL shows as https://<mysite>:8080 instead of the expected https://<mysite> only.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`proxy_redirect off`

to

`proxy_redirect http://localhost:8080/ http://$host/`

Comment: I tried making the proxy_redirect changes but the results were the same.  I believe the problem must be in the Docker wordpress image and the Apache configuration.  I'm going to look there and post what I find.